# forward slash in api url

Tags: javascript, regex, api, escaping, urlencode

I am using a zoom api to get meeting details.
I can get the details for few but it fails for those ids that have special characters in the beginning.

```
 url = BaseURL/metrics/meetings/{:uuid}
       BaseURL/metrics/meetings/+dh3d6dgdhj
       BaseURL/metrics/meetings/!kdh3d6dcncb
       BaseURL/metrics/meetings//ddcff3n348
```

I can escape characters + and ! with %2B and %21.
But when i try to escape the forward slash / with %2F the api fails. It does not recognize the first forward slash of meetingID: /ddcff3n348.
I cannot even run the forward slash id on Postman.

I am using a simple fetch to call zoom api:

```
const url = `${process.env.baseMetricsAPI}/meetings/${uuid}/participants${process.env.params}`; //meeting participants
                        let obj = {
                            method: 'GET',
                            headers:{
                                'authorization': 'Bearer' + access_token,
                            }
                        }

                            const response = await fetch(url, obj); 
                            let data = await response.json();
                            return data
```

Below are my findings in postman.
Here the api call is for uuid: /cxDLpgQTQabC5QM7OuiQ==. The api call fails saying the meeting doesn't exist because it is unable to recognize the forward slash '/'.

[image]

Replacing '/' with %2F or %252F in uuid: /cxDLpgQTQabC5QM7OuiQ==. The api call again fails.

[image]

[image]

Here the api call is for uuid: +/VLN+OjTROE9e2FfJHOA==. Replacing '+' with %2B in uuid, the api call is a success.

[image]

Replacing '+' and '/' in the uuid with %2B and %2F, the api still works.

[image]

So that means %2F doesn't work when it is in the beginning of the uuid. I think because it gets confused with the domain's forward slash. Any insights on this?

Comment: You could try double encoding. Instead of `%2F` try `%252F`. Not sure if it'll work but worth a try I think.

Comment: tried that too it did not work

Comment: Does Zoom provide any API documentation?

Comment: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/methods/#operation/meeting. everywhere they say u need to use %2F or %252F. i tested it on Postman and both do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post your code and what your before/after expected values are?

---

Per [the docs](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/methods/#operation/meeting):

> Unique meeting ID. Each meeting instance will generate its own Meeting UUID (i.e., after a meeting ends, a new UUID will be generated for the next instance of the meeting). You can retrieve a list of UUIDs from past meeting instances using the List past meeting instances API. **[Double encode](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/using-zoom-apis/#meeting-id-and-uuid) your UUID when using it for API calls if the UUID begins with a `/` or contains `//` in it.**

That link leads to this message:

> **Meeting ID and UUID**
>
> A meeting ID is a system-generated identifier of an instant or scheduled Zoom meeting. It is unique to the created meeting. A UUID is specific to the particular instance of a meeting. If you have a recurring meeting for example, a UUID is generated for each occurrence. While a meeting ID may expire 30 days after the last time it is used, a UUID does not. **When you see a note in the API that asks you to double encode a UUID that begins with a '/'or contains '//', you can go to the [URL encoder site](https://www.urlencoder.org) and encode it twice.**

---

Double-Encode Example:

```js
 const baseUrl = 'BaseURL/metrics/meetings/'
 const meetingIds = [ '+dh3d6dgdhj', '!kdh3d6dcncb', '/ddcff3n348' ]
 
 meetingIds.forEach(meetingId=>{
   meetingId = meetingId.replace(/\//g, encodeURIComponent)
   console.log(`${baseUrl}${encodeURIComponent(meetingId)}`)
 })
```

---

*Note: My account rating is below 50, which prohibited me from leaving some of this as a comment as I might ordinarily do. My apologies in advanced.*

Comment: Please check my updates

Comment: @Winterella did you look at your your network logs to make sure Poastman wasn't the one messing up your request? Have you tried `curl` or another tool to confirm?  It may be that zoom needs to be contacted.  They may have introduced a bug.